# CSS hyphens behaviour change in Chrome 55.0.2883.95

Tags: css, nowrap, css-hyphens

It seems like setting "hyphens" to "auto" now takes higher priority than "white-space: nowrap". 
In previous versions of Chrome (54 prior in Mac) and other browsers (FF, Safari, IE), it seems like "white-space: nowrap" outbids the hyphens.
So, if you specify white-space: nowrap and text-overflow: ellipsis, you see the text gets truncated with ellipsis regardless of hyphens setting.

Starting from 55.0.2883.95 (Mac version), it seems like hyphens: auto will do the line-wrapping even when white-space: nowrap is specified.
I agree that it sounds silly to specify hyphens and nowrap at the same time..
But since this is a "new" behaviour, I'd like to confirm whether this is a bug or an intended behaviour.

I created a simple fiddle for testing this issue for comparing behaviours across other browsers.

```css
div {
  width: 75px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
div.testCls {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
}
```

```html
<div lang="en" class="testCls">Anextremely long English word</div>
```

Screenshots:

[Chrome in Mac 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGqXF.png)

Comment: Can you add an image of what do you see? Chromium 55.0.2883.87 on Ubuntu behaves like Firefox.

Comment: Added a screenshot. My reputation point is so low, I cannot post another screenshot of FireFox.. In firefox, the content gets displayed as "Anextre..." in one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's chrome's problem; same code works fine in firefox and safari;

the way to fix this, just add hyphens:none; into ur truncate class.

Comment: Created an issue in Chromium to confirm whether it's a bug in Chrome or not. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=678356

Comment: Looks like they might "fix" this issue on their next version (56). I see the above ticket get tagged with M56.

Comment: Chrome fixed this issue in the next version. hyphens will only work when wrapping is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

As for Chrome using `hyphen: auto` if you look at [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=hyphens) you will see that the `auto` property for Chrome is not supported. And when I tested this no hyphens were shown in Chrome (unless you use the hyphens manual method).

Based on your question I didnt find formal documentation to answer your question but I tested your code on Chrome, Firefox and IE (on Windows) and found that using `white-space: nowrap;` in all cases caused the text not hyphenate. As long as the `nowrap` value is being used this also cause the `overflow: hidden;` element and `text-overflow: ellipsis;` to work as expected since both those elements need non wrapping text to showcase their properties. Hope that helps

Comment: caniuse says auto property is supported for Mac.. which is the version that I specified in the title. 55.0.2883.95. If you try my code (fiddle) in the latest Chrome using Mac, you will notice that hyphens will wrap the content even when hyphens is specified. So, it looks like hyphens starts working in chrome starting from 55.0.2883.95.. but why does it behave differently than the other browsers?

Comment: Gotcha. I will have to test it out when i get my hands on a Mac